# Restructuring a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

a need to restructure, or pick up the wanted, from a string

```
msg = ['Check-in  Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
   'Check-out Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)']


for each_guest in msg:
    each_guest = each_guest.replace('  ', ' ')
    action, name, room, number, at, date, time0, time1, recorded = each_guest.split(' ')

    print name, action, number, date, time0 + ':' + time1
```

above runs fine and the outputs are:

```
Jones Check-in 403 2014-11-02 05:20
Beis Check-out 302 2014-11-03 05:20
```

However it doesn’t work once the situation is changed. For example, the string is changed to:

```
msg = ['Check-in  Mr. Benny Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
   'Check-out Mr. Ken Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)']
```

The number of spaces in between in the words are uncertain. How can I have the full name (including the title) extracted, and put them in a way as the successful sample shown?

Comment: It would seem a whole lot easier to change the structure of your data to, say, a dictionary. Would that be an option?

Comment: Just so that we're clear: Do you want to divide the text in each lijne each line like this? `['Check-xxx', 'Mr. Person Name', 'Room xxx' 'at timegoeshere (recorded)']`

Comment: Just a comment to your current code: You don't need to replace 2 spaces by one space if you use `split()` without a parameter.

Comment: thanks, Tim Castelijns for the thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> msg = ['Check-in  Mr. Benny Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
...    'Check-out Mr. Ken Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)']
>>> for each_guest in msg:
...       m = re.match("([-_a-zA-Z]+)\s+(.*?)\s+Room\s+(\d+)\s+at\s+(\d+-\d+-\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\(recorded\)", each_guest)
...       action, name, number, date, time0, time1 = (m.group(i) for i in range(1, 7))
...       print(action, name, number, date, time0, time1)
('Check-in', 'Mr. Benny Jones', '403', '2014-11-02', '05', '20')
('Check-out', 'Mr. Ken Beis', '302', '2014-11-03', '05', '20')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's nothing you can do about the source data format (so you get something that's easier to parse), regexps are your friends. Your messages strings have a rather consistent pattern:

```
"<action> <name> Room <room number> at <date> (recorded)"
```

Where `action` is one of "Check-in" or "Check-out", `name` is free text, `room number` a sequence of digits and `date` is "YYYY-MM-DD HH MM" (well assume that's what it is). I'm not going to write down the exact regexp for it here but it's rather straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all other fields have fixed length (no additional white spaces) this works:

```
msg = ['Check-in  Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
   'Check-out Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)',
   'Check-in  Mr. Benny Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
   'Check-out Mr. Ken Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)']


for each_guest in msg:
    each_guest = each_guest.replace('  ', ' ')
    splits = each_guest.split()
    action = splits[0]
    date_and_time = ' '.join(splits[-4:-2])
    roomnumber = splits[-6]
    name = ' '.join(splits[1:-7])

    print name, action, roomnumber, date_and_time
```

it prints

```
Jones Check-in 403 2014-11-02 05
Beis Check-out 302 2014-11-03 05
Mr. Benny Jones Check-in 403 2014-11-02 05
Mr. Ken Beis Check-out 302 2014-11-03 05
```

Answer (score 1):

As you strings have a fixed structure you can use regex for this(preferably with named groups):

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^(?P<check>[-\w]+)\s+(?P<name>.*(?=\s\sRoom))\s+Room\s+(?P<room>\d+)\s+at\s+(?P<date>\S+)\s(?P<hour>\d+)\s(?P<min>\d+)')
msg = ['Check-in  Mr. Benny Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
       'Check-out Mr. Ken Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)',
       'Check-in  Jones  Room  403 at 2014-11-02 05 20 (recorded)',
       'Check-out Beis  Room  302 at 2014-11-03 05 20 (recorded)']

for m in msg:
    groups = r.search(m).groupdict()
    print '{name} {check} {room} {date} {hour}:{min}'.format(**groups)
```

Output:

```
Mr. Benny Jones Check-in 403 2014-11-02 05:20
Mr. Ken Beis Check-out 302 2014-11-03 05:20
Jones Check-in 403 2014-11-02 05:20
Beis Check-out 302 2014-11-03 05:20
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `string.index`, something like this can extract the full name and other information:

```
# i purposefully not assigning names to different indexes so you're more clear on how it works
for each in msg:
    each = each.split()
    print each[0], \
      ' '.join(each[1:each.index('Room')]), \
      each[each.index('Room')+1], \
      each[each.index('at')+1], \
      ':'.join(each[each.index('at')+2:each.index('(recorded)')]) # date time

Check-in Mr. Benny Jones 403 2014-11-02 05:20
Check-out Mr. Ken Beis 302 2014-11-03 05:20
```